# What is the equivalent javascript code for php's mysql_real_escape_string()?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql-injection

What is the equivalent javascript code for `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

Comment: There isn't any, because strings that come from javascript are still considered 'user input' and should **never be inserted in your database directly**. Your serverside has to do additional validation. There are functions to encode URLs and stuff like that. **What are you trying to do**?

Comment: Well, the PHP documentation says: *mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: `\x00`, `\n`, `\r`, `\`, `'`, `"` and `\x1a`.* So it should be trivial to implement this. But why do you need this? Don't think that only if you use it at the client side, you don't have to use it at the server side. **Never** trust user input (i.e. all data that is sent to your server).

Comment: I don't know about the original asker but I'm doing this to convert data from a web app into a MySQL database.  Just because someone wants to do something in javascript doesn't mean they're building a web site.  I'm making a single HTML file that I can open locally and click a button to generate MySQL insert statements and eventually some java code that will be pasted into an android app to setup a database.  This will be rerun occasionally to generate database update scripts for future versions of the same android app.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) of the method this would do roughly the same thing.  The method mysql_real_escape_string in PHP is deprecated however.

```
function mysqlEscape(stringToEscape){
    return stringToEscape
        .replace("\\", "\\\\")
        .replace("\'", "\\\'")
        .replace("\"", "\\\"")
        .replace("\n", "\\\n")
        .replace("\r", "\\\r")
        .replace("\x00", "\\\x00")
        .replace("\x1a", "\\\x1a");
}
```

Unfortunately that's not exactly what mysql_real_escape_string does according to the [5.6 mysql API docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html).  It doesn't take into account character encodings among other things.

The above method will likely do what you're looking for even if you only use the first 2 replaces like so.

```
function mysqlEscape(stringToEscape){
    return stringToEscape
        .replace("\\", "\\\\")
        .replace("\'", "\\\'");
}
```

According to the mysql docs.

> MySQL requires only that backslash and the quote character used to quote the string in the query be escaped. mysql_real_escape_string() quotes the other characters to make them easier to read in log files

Comment: This will only replace the first occurrence of each special symbol.

Answer (score 2):

A good tip when you're looking for javascript equivalent versions of popular PHP functions is

[phpjs.org](http://phpjs.org)

However your probably looking for the wrong functionality. mysql_real_escape_string() can only be used if a mysql database connection is active (More details about this can be read on the [mysqli real_escape page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). I.e mysql_real_escape_string() isn't really a PHP implementation, but more MySQL. If used without database connection it will just leave you with an empty variable.

You might have looked for a function that adds slashes and removes newlines? You can check the phpjs.org on how they implemented the add_slashes function. Removing newlines can be done with a custom replace function I guess.

Maybe explain in what environment you require this function to work in javascript, so we could push you in the right direction (i.e talk you out of using mysql_real_escape_string in javascript but provide tips on which function(s) you really need)

Answer (score 2):

I've had an use case where I need to escape my own data (not from user input) in order to use it within a node.js script. I've fixed the code from @majinnaibu answer, because it was only escaping the first occurrence of the special symbol.

```
function mysqlEscape(stringToEscape){
    if(stringToEscape == '') {
        return stringToEscape;
    }

    return stringToEscape
        .replace(/\\/g, "\\\\")
        .replace(/\'/g, "\\\'")
        .replace(/\"/g, "\\\"")
        .replace(/\n/g, "\\\n")
        .replace(/\r/g, "\\\r")
        .replace(/\x00/g, "\\\x00")
        .replace(/\x1a/g, "\\\x1a");
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any, because strings that come from JavaScript are still considered 'user input' and **should never be inserted in your database directly**. Your server-side has to do additional validation. There are functions to encode URLs and stuff like that.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: JavaScript is not *just* a client-side language.  Node.js and Mozilla Rhino are two examples of software which use the JavaScript language in non-browser settings.  To ask for JavaScript code to replicate the majority of that functionality is perfectly reasonable (remembering that mysql_real_escape_string() cares about which database is being used, there's an element of the code that will certainly be dependent upon the environment in which the JavaScript is being run .. regardless, this has plenty of applications outside of the browser).

Comment: @Josh1billion: you are right, and my answer should have made a note of the exception. However, since the question was not tagged Node/serverside/Rhino/... I still think it wise to err on the cautious side. If you know any javascript functions that do what the author wants, do post an answer of your own.

Comment: I don't know of any, unfortunately, but I wish I did.  The way I found this question was by googling in hopes of finding one.

Answer (score -1):

I think we can use escape() methode

Comment: No, you can't. After escape, data is still not ready to be put in a database. You **need** serverside validation. Don't forget anyone can edit your javascript variables at any point.

Comment: Unless you're not using it for database stuff - in which case your question was misleading. If it's for passing to another URL or stuff like that, escape() or htmlentities() might work. But that's not what `mysql_real_escape_string()` is for :)