# PHP's mysqli_real_escape_string equivalent in Google Apps Script

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script

What is the PHP's **mysqli_real_escape_string** equivalent in Google Apps Script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent javascript code for php's mysql\_real\_escape\_string()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191062/what-is-the-equivalent-javascript-code-for-phps-mysql-real-escape-string)

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT**

This might be what you're looking for:
[What is the equivalent javascript code for php's mysql_real_escape_string()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191062/what-is-the-equivalent-javascript-code-for-phps-mysql-real-escape-string)

---

<strike>Google Apps Script is based on Javascript and by virtue of that lineage you have the following options at your disposal:</strike>

- [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)
- [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

They may not grant you exact parity with PHP's `mysqli_real_escape_string` but they should get you close to what you need.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent` performs URL-encoding, it doesn't do the escaping required for MySQL.